# onClick Dropdown menu Responsive Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on making my site responsive and so I needed to have a decent menu for the mobile view.
So i got myself a button which only pops up when im in 480px or lower which is good. But the problem is:
**Making the menu drop down won't work.** All I need is an simple dropdown menu but i cant manage to make it work.

jQuery Link:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="mobimenu">
    <a href="#menu">
    <img src="threelines.png" alt="menu button">
    </a>
    <div id="mobidrop">
        menu comes here
    </div>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
        #mobimenu{
            display: none;
        }

        #mobidrop{
            display:none;
        }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    #mobimenu {
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }

    #mobidrop{

        width: 100px;
        height:50px;
        background-color: red;
    }

}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){$("#mobimenu").on('click', function() {
   $("#mobidrop").show();
});
```

Comment: You are missing closing `});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some closing quotes/parenthesis in the jQuery code..

It should be

```
$(function(){
    $("#mobimenu").on('click', function() {
      $("#mobidrop").show();
   });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Wj8k5/
(*make the window small so you can see the mobile version*)

Comment: Some platforms like wordpress need `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: @Shikez, are you running it locally? from your disk and not from a web-server ?

Comment: locally at the moment but if needed i can temp put it online

Comment: @Shikez if with locally you mean you just open the html file in the browser then you will have to add `http:` to the script and css urls of jquery or they are not being included.. You should check your console for errors to make sure the code runs correct.

Comment: That was the problem haha only thing is it wont dropback in when i click the icon again

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli got this code now `$(function(){
    $("#mobimenu").on('click', function() {
       $("#mobidrop").show();
       $("#three").hide();
       $("#mobitoggle").show();
    });
});
$(function(){
    $("#mobitoggle").on('click', function() {
       $("#mobidrop").hide();
       $("#three").show();
       $("#mobitoggle").hide();
    });
});`

Comment: @Shikez just do `$("#mobidrop").toggle();` instead of `$("#mobidrop").show();` ***Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/Wj8k5/2/*